About the dimension of the support of higherdirect image of coherent sheaf.
I'm reading a proof of Proposition 5.77 (1) in Birational geometry by Kollar,Mori.
Proposition $(1)$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be projective scheme of pure dimension $n$ over a field $k$  and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a generically finite morpohism.
At the begining of proof, it writes
"Let $F$ be any coherent sheaf on $X$. $\mathrm{Supp} R^jf_*F$ has dimension at most $n-j-1$ for $j>0$."
Why is this true??
If possible , I want to know a refference book about this fact.
